# Completeness of $\delta_n = e_n + e_{n+1}$ with $e_n$ a complex exponential

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $e_n(x) = e^{2 \pi i n x}$. It is well-known that $\{ e_n | n \in \mathbb Z \}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2[-1/2,1/2]$. In particular, $\{ e_n | n \in \mathbb Z\}$ is complete in $L^2[-1/2,1/2]$. Now let $\delta_n = e_n + e_{n+1}$. I was wondering if the system $\{ \delta_n | n \in \mathbb Z \}$ is complete in $L^2[-1/2,1/2]$ as well. Or more general: let
$$\delta_n = \sum e_{k(n)}
$$
be a finite non-trivial linear combiniation of $e_{k(n)}$. Is the system $\{ \delta_n : n \in \mathbb Z \}$ complete in $L^2[-1/2,1/2]$?

Comment: Does $e_0$ belong to the linear span of $\{ \delta_n | n \in \mathbb Z \}$?  To the closed linear span?

Comment: It does not belong to the linear span but I'm not sure if it belongs to the closed linear span. If yes it would mean that we can approximate $e_0 = 1$ arbitrarily well by linear combination of $\delta_n$'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general let $\{e_n\}_{n=-\infty}^\infty$ be an orthonormal basis of an infinite dimensional Hilbert space. Then the set $\{e_n+e_{n+1}\}$ is linearly dense. Indeed, it suffices to show that there is no nonzero element $x$ such that $x\perp e_n+e_{n+1}$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}.$ By the Parseval identity we have
$$\|x\|^2=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |\langle x,e_n\rangle |^2$$ If $x\perp e_n+e_{n+1}$ then $$\langle x,e_n\rangle=-\langle x,e_{n+1}\rangle$$ Hence
$$|\langle x,e_n\rangle|=|\langle x,e_{n+1}\rangle|$$ which shows that the sequence $|\langle x,e_n\rangle|$ is constant. As it is square summable, then $\langle x,e_n\rangle=0$ for any $n,$ i.e. $x=0.$

Alternatively it can be shown
that $$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\left (1-{k\over n}\right)[e_k+e_{k+1}]$$ approximate $e_0.$ Simlarly we can approximate any element $e_m.$

The statement can be generalized. For example let $$\delta_n=e_n+e_{n+1}+\ldots +\delta_{n+k-1}$$ for a fixed $k.$ Assume $x\perp \delta_n$ for any $n.$ Then the sequence $a_n:=\langle x,e_n\rangle$ satisfies
$$a_n+a_{n+1}+\ldots +a_{n+k-1}=0,\quad n\in \mathbb{Z}\quad (*)$$ Therefore
$$a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+\ldots +a_{n+k}=0,\quad n\in \mathbb{Z}\quad (**)$$ Subtracting $(**)$ and $(*)$ implies $a_n=a_{n+k},$ i.e. the sequence $a_n$ is periodic with period $k.$ Since $a_n$ is square summable we get $a_n=0$ for all $n,$ hence $x=0.$

Comment: Great, thank you! Does a similar statement work if the linear combination consist of more than two vectors? Or would it fail there?

Comment: It works for $e_{n-1}+e_n+e_{n+1}$ for example. I think it works in general as the sequence $a_n:=\langle x,e_n\rangle$ would have to satisfy a recurrence relation with constant coefficients, indexed by the integers. Any nontrivial solution of such recurrence relation is not square summable. It is essential that the sequence is indexed by the integers.